# How to get value from Task

Tags: c#

Need to extract the value from the System.Threadding.Tasks.Task as when i call a method its returning a Task as return value.

Am using the Task to find any property inside to get the value but there is no property i find to get the value.

The target method is like below.

```
public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
        {
            object response = null;
            ResponseCollection<Model> data = (ResponseCollection<Model>)context.Object;
            if (data != null && data.Records != null)
            {
                List<Response> Response = Mapper.Map<List<Model>, List<Response>>(data.Records);
                response = Response;
            }
            DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            };

            return context.HttpContext.Response
            .WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = contractResolver,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            }), selectedEncoding);
        }
```

and I tried to call the method in the below fashion but all am getting is the task but I need to get the response from the task.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SuccessTest()
{
    MyFormatter formatter = new MyFormatter();

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("customheader1", "9");
    httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("customheader2", "10");
    Func<Stream, Encoding, TextWriter> func = NewMethod;
    OutputFormatterWriteContext context = new OutputFormatterWriteContext(httpContext, func, null, GetModel());

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Model, Response>();
    });

    formatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(context, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode).Wait();

    string responseBody = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Response.Body).ReadToEnd();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
}

private TextWriter NewMethod(Stream arg1, Encoding arg2)
{
    return new StreamWriter(arg1, arg2);
}
```

now, how can I find the response from the result which is of type Task?

This is noting but building a custum media formatter and unit testing the same. I built the formatter but when unit testing i need the response object as i need to assert.
I cant return a Task as you can see the return type of WriteAsync method is Task and i have to return that.

Comment: you `await` them

Comment: but its not an async method. We can use the await only for async methods right?

Comment: Your method doesn't return any value. You probably need a `Task<T>`.

Comment: what is the context object?

Comment: @user3625533 "but its not an async method." - then it either a: shouldn't be asking about the result of tasks (unless it knows they will always be fully completed by now), or b: it needs to *become* an async method

Comment: context is httpcontext. Actually am building a custom media formatter and unit testing the same. Formatter working as expected now i need to unit test this piece of code which i wrote. so to assert i need the actual response.

Comment: " i need the response object as i need to assert"  You already have the response object inside the context. Because you are passing it as the first parameter. All you need to do is wait for the Task to complete and inspect it. However, I'm not sure if  you can inspect an actual response. You might have to moq it.

Comment: @Marc Gravell When i call the method i am getting the Task and the task status is "RanToCompletion" that means the task is completed

Comment: @user3625533 but will it *always* be completed? or is that just coincidence...?

Answer (score 2):

You have to `await` `async` methods. `Task` is a wrapper for the result that optionally resolves to a value and keeps a context of the thread for capturing exceptions.

```
await formatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(context, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);
```

However, in your code, you return just a `Task`. There is no actual return value so you shouldn't expect to get anything back from the function except the completion of it itself. If you need to return a specific value from an `async` function, you should wrap the type in a `Task` i.e. `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an async write operation on a http context. Once you await the write operation, you can access the response in the next statement

```
await formatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(context, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);
```

Since you are not performing this in an async method, you can use the `Wait()` method to wait synchronously.

```
formatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(context, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode).Wait();
```

A http resonse is a stream that gets pushed to the client as it is being written. In order to read the response you have to open a stream reader and read the body. And you have to do it after the write operation is complete.

```
// Read the response body
string responseBody = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Response.Body).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: @user3625533 did you try this?

Comment: tried it but the response body am getting as empty string and getting the status code as 200 that means the response should e generated.

Comment: That's because you are writing a `null` value. `object response=null;`

Comment: updated my question with actual code. iam injecting a response from the unit test case and  it has to transform into another model then has to be overriden in response object by my formater code. but still am getting empty string.